# How can I set the color of a specific line in a libgdx list?

Tags: list, libgdx, scene2d

I am developing a list and I want to highlight certain lines by showing the font color in red. Is this possible?

EDIT:
Ok, here a simplified version of my code:

```
Skin defListSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));

List listHistory = new List<String>(defSkin);

// Here I set the general font color for the list
List.ListStyle listStyle = listHistory.getStyle();
listStyle.font = fontList;
listStyle.fontColorUnselected = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
listHistory.setStyle(listStyle);

String[] items = new String[20];

// Example of item[]
// item[0]: "John   12"
// item[1]: "Amy    -3" <-- I want certain lines to appear in red (e.g. those with negative numbers)

// Populate the list
listHistory.setItems(items);

// Drawing the list (actual draw happens in render() of course)
Table myTable = new Table();
myTable.add(listHistory);
stage.addActor(myTable);
```

Comment: Far too vague :) give us what you've tried and maybe screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How are you currently drawing your lines? Do you have some kind of `List<String>`. You can probably do `spriteBatch.setColor(..)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Color Markup Language that Libgdx supports.

The markup syntax is really simple but still versatile:

[name] Sets the color by name. There are a few predefined colors, see the Colors.reset() method for an exhaustive list. Users can define their own colors through the methods of the Colors class.
[#xxxxxxxx] Sets the color specified by the hex value xxxxxxxx in the form RRGGBBAA where AA is optional and defaults to 0xFF.
[] Sets the color to the previous color (kind of optional end tag)
[[ Escapes the left bracket.

**Markup is disabled by default. Use the public member font.getData().markupEnabled to turn it on/off.**

Reference: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Color-Markup-Language

If you want a more complex html like markup you can use those templates: https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml, live tests: http://czyzby.github.io/gdx-lml-tests/

Comment: Excellent - it works! I didn't know about the Color Markup Language. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean, and I don't think it is possible.  The list items are all linked to the same listStyle, and the only way to change the color of the list items is to make a new style for listHistory and change the font color of this style, however if you do this, it changes every item in the list to that new font color.  My suggestion would be to create two separate lists and two separate ListStyles and the lines you want red be in one list and have one style and the lines you don't want to be red be in another list and have a different style. Hope this helps